# WinEdtPDF giving invalid floating point exception after reboot (PC, Win 10/11, WinEdt 11.1)

Tags: latex

I have been using the WinEdtPDF viewer with WinEdt V11.1 without issues. However, immediately after a reboot it now reports:

```
            Exception ElnvalidOp in module WinEdtPDF.exe at
            0000000000436509.
            Invalid floating point operation.
```

whenever I attempt to open it.

The problem occurs irrespective of how I attempt to open WinEdtPDF, e.g. whether opening from within WinEdt, from the file manager, or from a command line (with admin priviledges). This same problem occurs on 2 different devices, one running Win 10 and the other Win 11. Both devices have had recent updates to their OS (which is potentially the cause of the issue).  I have reinstalled WinEdt v11.1 (which includes WinEdtPDF) and the problem remains.

Is anyone else having this problem? Does anyone know a solution, or have a suggestion to try? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be caused by Windows corrupting the file WinEdtPDF.dat when it forces a close of WinEdtPDF before restarting.  The corrupted file needs to be deleted and a fresh copy generated.

In **WinEdt** navigate as follows:
Options / Configuration Wizard / Browse Local Folder
This will open File Explorer.  Open the PDF subfolder.
Delete the file WinEdtPDF.dat.

Restart WinEdtPDF and a new WinEdtPDF.dat file will be generated automatically. All settings and recent file history will be lost, unfortunately.

Thanks to the WinEdt Team for the solution.